# Connect/authenticate to MongoDB using MongoDB driver for Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to MongoDB v3.6 using latest [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) MongoDB driver for Node.js and getting `MongoError: not authorized to database`.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url)
        .then((client)  => {
                const db = client.db('admin');
                console.log(db);
            })
        .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I once had a problem when my password contained some special characters like `@` and `#`. Try passing your credentials in the `options` parameter: `MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { auth: { user: 'user', password: 'password' } })`

Comment: Thank you!  Seems, in my case previous user had not right permission, even though I could connect and read data from mongo shell. I added new user and it works.